# Method 'Range of object' _Worksheet' failed -- but only if I call the sub from another sub

Tags: excel, vba

The failure occurs at the line beginning with "Set x = "

This may be the big clue: When I run this code as a separate sub, it runs fine. I only get the error when I call this sub from *another* sub. Why should this be the case?

```
Option Explicit

Sub EIRPChartUpdate()
'update EIRP Chart
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim x As Range, y1 As Range, y2 As Range, y3 As Range, y4 As Range
    Dim points As Long

    Set EIRPChart = Sheets("EIRP Chart")
    Set EIRPSummary = Sheets("EIRP Summary")

    'get last row of EIRP Summary
    lastEIRPSummaryRow = EIRPSummary.Cells.Find("*", [A1], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row

    'count the number of data points
    points = lastEIRPSummaryRow - [ESDataRow1].Row + 1

'set independent and dependent data ranges
With EIRPSummary
    Set x = .Range(Cells([ESDataRow1].Row, [ESCaseNum].Column), Cells(lastEIRPSummaryRow, [ESCaseNum].Column))
    Set y1 = .Range(Cells([ESDataRow1].Row, [ESPriSpec100].Column), Cells(lastEIRPSummaryRow, [ESPriSpec100].Column))
    Set y2 = .Range(Cells([ESDataRow1].Row, [ESPriPred100].Column), Cells(lastEIRPSummaryRow, [ESPriPred100].Column))
    Set y3 = .Range(Cells([ESDataRow1].Row, [ESPriPred95].Column), Cells(lastEIRPSummaryRow, [ESPriPred95].Column))
    Set y4 = .Range(Cells([ESDataRow1].Row, [ESPriPred90].Column), Cells(lastEIRPSummaryRow, [ESPriPred90].Column))
End With

'more code ...
```

Comment: try to add period `.` also before `Cells` like this: `Set x = .Range(.Cells([ESDataRow1].Row, [ESCaseNum].Column), .Cells(lastEIRPSummaryRow, [ESCaseNum].Column))`

Comment: @simoco that worked. You have done it again and I am much obliged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As follow up from comments,

`Cells` should be fully qualified, i.e. you should specify sheet to which cells belongs:

```
With EIRPSummary
    Set x = .Range(.Cells([ESDataRow1].Row, [ESCaseNum].Column), .Cells(lastEIRPSummaryRow, [ESCaseNum].Column))
    Set y1 = .Range(.Cells([ESDataRow1].Row, [ESPriSpec100].Column), .Cells(lastEIRPSummaryRow, [ESPriSpec100].Column))
    Set y2 = .Range(.Cells([ESDataRow1].Row, [ESPriPred100].Column), .Cells(lastEIRPSummaryRow, [ESPriPred100].Column))
    Set y3 = .Range(.Cells([ESDataRow1].Row, [ESPriPred95].Column), .Cells(lastEIRPSummaryRow, [ESPriPred95].Column))
    Set y4 = .Range(.Cells([ESDataRow1].Row, [ESPriPred90].Column), .Cells(lastEIRPSummaryRow, [ESPriPred90].Column))
End With
```

Comment: I thought that by specifying the sheet to which the range belongs, the cells within would also be specified to the same sheet, but I now see this is not the case. Thanks again.